# Is it possible to pass additional HTTP headers along with Weaviate module requests using the python client?

Tags: weaviate

Is it possible to force a Weaviate module to pass additional headers along with requests?

e.g. we can initialize the [python weaviate client](https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/weaviate.client.html#weaviate.client.Client) with `additional_headers`

```py
client = weaviate.Client(
    '<db_url>',
    additional_headers={'X-OpenAI-Organization': '<openai-org-id>'},
)
```

But that header is not passed along by the `text2vec-openai` module.

[The module configuration docs suggest that the API key can be provided with ^this exact pattern](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/modules/retriever-vectorizer-modules/text2vec-openai#provide-the-api-key), so I was hoping the organization id could be passed as well.  But it doesn't work.

Is there another approach that will work?